# reloading a changed module in python have a delay?

Tags: python, import, reload

I have a function that changes the module based on a passed function then import that module to use it. but when I change the module once then import it, it's as intended then I changed it again with no time delay the imported module is just it was in the first change

this is the function that creates the module

```
import sys
from time import sleep
def get_fun(text_fun):
    with open('plotFun.py', 'w') as plotFun:
        plotFun.write(f'class FunctionObject():\n\tdef function_object(self, x=None):\n\t\ty = {text_fun}\n\t\treturn "{{:.2f}}".format(y)')

    # import the created class
    if 'plotFun' not in sys.modules:
        from plotFun import FunctionObject
    else:
        del sys.modules["plotFun"]
        from plotFun import FunctionObject
    
    # create an instance of the created class
    my_fun =  FunctionObject()
    
    # check if the function inputted from user is a valid function
    try:
        my_fun.function_object(3.14)
    except NameError:
        raise ValueError('Invalid Function')
    # pass any other errors, they will be found later when the function is used.
    except:
        pass

    return my_fun

def main():
    y1 = get_fun('2*3')
    print(y1.function_object())
    sleep(1)
    y2 = get_fun('3*3')
    print(y2.function_object())

main()
```

with this code the print is
6.00
9.00
but if I removed sleep(1) both print are 6.00
I tried sleep(0.1) but still both are 6.00
but when I tried sleep(0.7) it changed. it's like I have to delay for a specific time for the function to change

Answer (score 1):

Python reuses the byte-compiled version of your module if the source [appears to be unmodified](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#pyc-invalidation).  The default mechanism is based on the size and modification time of the file: the size doesn’t change here, and the modification time is stored/checked with a **granularity** of, often, 1 second.